# Post observable array to code behind

Tags: knockout.js

```
null value of observable array when i use this code how can i solved

self.items = ko.observableArray([]);
var jsonText = JSON.stringify({ myColumns: self.items() });
```

in quick watch i see that  {"myColumns":[{}]} but array is fulled from obseravble property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the built in `ko.toJSON` method (See http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/json-data.html)

```
var jsonText = ko.toJSON(self);
```